# iOS Simulator - Record simulator screen and include device frame?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

Is it possible to record a video of both the simulator screen and the device? I'm able to take video recording of JUST the simulator screen (with cmmd + r), but I'd like to record my app inside the actual device (and have the actual phone be part of the video). Been looking online everywhere and I can't seem to find how to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: I just record, then use [rotato](https://www.rotato.app/) to embed it in the frame

Comment: Ok, you are the greatest human. Just downloaded it and it's AWESOME. Thank you so much @aheze :)

Answer (score 0):

Quicktime can record your device.  Here is the guide:
https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/quicktime-player/qtp356b55534/mac

scroll down to:
Use an iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch connected to your Mac

Cheers!

Comment: This allows me to record the screen of my device, but I'm trying to record the actual iPhone shell/frame with the screen in the simulator? E.g. I want my video to appear inside an actual phone graphic?

Comment: Ah, sorry, misunderstood. :)

Comment: Haha all good! :) Hilariously I didn't know you could do that with Quicktime - def a trick I'll be using for other circumstances.

Comment: @Brittany did you end up finding a way to do this? :)

Comment: @kreeguy100 I ended up downloading Rotato! This allowed me to drop my video into an actual device. https://rotato.app Super worth it, super useful.